# Android transactions hang ui thread?

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
    Cursor cursor = fetchAllPhoneNumbers();
    mDb.beginTransaction();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.KEY_CONTACT_ID));
        String phoneNo = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.KEY_CONTACT_NO));
        String key = contactId + "," + phoneNo;
        String reg = map.get(key);
        if (reg != null) { 

            updatePhoneNumbersIsRegistered(contactId, phoneNo,
                    reg, System.currentTimeMillis());
        } else {

            deletePhoneNumbersByContactDetail(contactId, phoneNo);
        }
        map.remove(key);

    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> pnEntry : map.entrySet()) {
        String pnKey = pnEntry.getKey();
        String pnValue = pnEntry.getValue();
        String[] details = pnKey.split(",");

        createPhoneNumber(details[0], details[1], pnValue,
                System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    cursor.close();

    mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
    mDb.endTransaction();
```

Running this function in an AsyncTask causes my ui thread to hang until the function is completed, **but if I remove the begin, set and end transaction the ui thread runs freely**, any idea why this is happening or is there a work around? This actually boosted performance from 2 mins to 20 secs when i placed the transaction codes.(Do note it was for testing so i did not do a proper try catch finally to handle the endtransaction.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally put this kinda stuff in a `IntentService`, which runs on a different thread, and then handle communications between the service and UI with a `Handler`.

Comment: It actually is in a service as well that's why i'm baffled why it freezes the ui, if I'm not wrong the service is tied to the ui thread as well?

Comment: yeah, a normal service will run in the UI thread (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), but an `IntentService` is run on a seperate thread (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Comment: Ok will try this tomorrow, I'm at home right now. Oh just read another thread, this is very cool, it actually queues up the service intents! It's something i will really look forward to.

Comment: Hope it works for you - feel free to hit me up for help if you need it along the way.

Comment: Ok it doesn't work. Once the housekeep kicks in, as in the function above, the whole ui freezes.

Comment: Accepting as answer for suggesting intent service. But ui freezing bug still there.

Comment: @Maurice have you find the solution of this problem? Right now i am facing the same problem and did not able to find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

This answers your question:

[Sqlite transaction is blocking Android ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890371/sqlite-transaction-is-blocking-android-ui)

Basically, something on the UI thread is trying to read the database and it hangs.  Make sure you perform no DB operations at all while the background thread is running.

Comment: For me, something as simple as setting some menu items based on the database state was enough to hang up my UI thread

Comment: I faced same issue, thanks for information. Is there any fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or implement thread to do your background work.

Comment: sorry jsut added, i knew someone would say this.

Comment: if AsyncTask is causing the problem then do it in thread or if you are doing your task in service then also you should do it in a separate thread as service uses main UI thread of the app..